# Is there no keyboard interface for Firefox and Safari "drop-down" windows?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, hotkeys

I switched to using OS X over a year ago and not being able to do some things with the keyboard, having to use the TouchPad on my MacBook Pro is just irritating.  Like a tiny splinter in my finger every time I "bump" into a drop down dialog box in the browser that requires Submit or Cancel.  In other pop-up windows, and just about ever other interface, I can use the keyboard to interact with the form or buttons.  What is the keyboard interface for interacting with these browser drop-down panels?  See the following screen capture:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Keyboard Shortcuts` tab > enable `Full Keyboard Access` at the bottom as in the shot below:

http://cl.ly/3Oem

Comment: Any reason why this is not enabled by default?

Comment: Used to be up to 10.6 as far as I remember. I have no idea why the random decision to switch it off by default.

P.S. `space` selects the border-highlighted option, `enter` the fully-highlighted one. Only the border-highlighted one changes via `tab`.

Comment: I don't ever remember it being enabled by default, though I may have just forgotten. In any case it is probably disabled by default to keep people from accidently confirming something they did not want to confirm.